# Non-ascii character "ö" in website title displaying as "Ã¶"

Tags: html, title

This is my title tag in the head:

```
    <title>Title with ö in it</title>
```

I've tried using different encoding:

```
    <title>Title with &#337; in it</title>
```

... but that just displays the same way!

Neither Safari nor Chrome displays ö correctly.

Comment: Are you setting the charset meta element?

Comment: The one-character-becomes-two is usually caused by ISO-8859[-1[5]] visualization of UTF8 characters, i.e. incorrect encoding of the page. What is the advertised encoding? If it is not UTF-8, *any* browser trusting the encoding will appear to misbehave.

Comment: This <meta charset="UTF-8"> is what @Rob had in mind

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

immediately after your opening

```
<html>
```

tag